# Несколько div-ов в ряд, как их растянуть на всю ширину экрана

Tags: html, css

Сайт пример, на котором пробую - http://testsite482.vacau.com/6/

Идет несколько div-ов в ряд. Один с синим фоном, другой с зеленым, третий уже внизу и с красным. При нажатии на кнопку "2" на первом или "3" на втором div-е идет прокрутка с помощью явы до следующего.

Вопрос такой, как растянуть эти дивы на всю ширину экрана, потому что впоследствии на каждом из фонов должен быть текст прямо по середине, и не хочется, что бы на разных разрешениях экрана этот текст скакал. Т.е что бы синий фон был ровно по ширине и высоте экрана и ни сантиметром дальше. Нажал на кнопочку 2, он прокрутился до зеленого, который в свою очередь тоже будет на весь экран, итд. Задача по сути исходит из за дальнейшей проблемы с позиционированием объектов, на разных разрешениях экрана, текст и кнопки, которые там в дальнейшем появятся, скачут по всему экрану в зависимости от разрешения оного. Как это правильно сделать?

Спасибо!

Comment: java!=javascript - не говорите "ява" когда имеете ввиду js. это не модный слэнг, это два абсолютно разных языка.

Comment: а может быть у него Java-апплеты на странице? :D

Comment: Может быть всё-таки использовать таблицу? :)

Answer (score 2):

Попробуй с помощью `CSS`:

```
div {
    position: fixed;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Так же можно попробовать с помощью `jQuery` вычислить размеры окна и встроить эти значения в `html`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function divresize(a) {
        var windowHeight = $(window).height();
        var b=$(a).html();
        $(a).html(b.replace("height:120","height:"+windowHeight)) //120 - первоначальная высота
    } divresize('div')
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю как в IE и Опере но в Firefox работает:

```
<html><head>
<style>
body{margin:0; padding:0;}
.a{ width:100%;height:100%;background-color:blue;}
.b{ width:100%;height:100%;background-color:green;}
.c{ width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background-color:red;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="a">тест</div>
<div class="b">тест 2</div>
<div class="c">тест 3</div>

</body></html>
```

Comment: и без всяких там Java-Script :)